# SqlPlus sessions in parallel OR keeping the session alive after disconnecting

Tags: oracle, bash, session, sqlplus

I have asked a question that can look similar to this one, but its about something different.

Lets assume that I have no privileges to run `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL` from the account on which I'm running Oracle packages.

On the other hand, I have access to a account that has privileges to run `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL`, but from that accound I cannot run the Oracle packages. A bit mixed up, but that's how it has to be for now.

Now, I have a Bash script, let me assume that in its current version it is running packages in  this manner:

The part that is responsible for the flush:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect sysuser/syspassword@db_instance
alter system flush shared_pool;
quit
```

The part responsible for the packages:

```
sqlplus user/password@db_instance @sqlfile.sql
```

And the `sqlfile.sql` (simplified as possible):

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,parameter);
print rc;
exit
```

Until everything looks like this - it is working fine. But there are examples, when I have to run several packages one after another, cause they are depending on each others output data that is kept in a `TEMPORARY_TABLE`. **I am absolutely sure that at least the data from the** `TEMPORARY TABLE` **is flushed when disconnecting**. So even if the `TEMPORARY_TABLE` is kept alive after disconnecting, the data is lost. The example of a multi-package `sqlfile.sql`:

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,1);
print rc;
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,2);
print rc;
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,3);
print rc;
exit
```

Because what I'm doing is for the testing purposes of the Oracle package output and performance, I have to run

```
alter system flush shared_pool
```

After each `exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,parameter)` occurence. If there is only one, its no problem. But if there are many, and they depend on each other... the problem starts to occur.

```
sqlplus /nolog << EOF

connect user/password@db_instance
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,1);
print rc;
connect sysuser/syspassword@db_instance
alter system flush shared_pool;

connect user/password@db_instance
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,2);
print rc;
connect sysuser/syspassword@db_instance
alter system flush shared_pool;

connect user/password@db_instance
variable rc refcursor;
exec :rc := package.function(parameter,parameter,3);
print rc;
connect sysuser/syspassword@db_instance
alter system flush shared_pool;

exit
EOF
```

The script itself is working - but the data from `TEMPORARY_TABLE` is lost.

I thought about running two sqlplus commands in bash in parallel, but the **flush** has to be runned at a precise moment... I just don't know how to approach this problem, it is enough to make angels weep.

Comment: That's an architectural issue, not a technical issue. The first thing I'm thinking is : how does it come you have to do all these kind of things, while you could just have one user that could run all of the above, as that one user ? Using SYSDBA should not be mixed with data manipulation, so you know which user should be used. Did you ask your DBA why he does not want to give you the right that is needed for "user" ? What is the reason ?

Comment: @tvCa - admin granted me the privilege to run `alter system flush shared_pool` from my database user, now everything is fine :)

Comment: That's exactly the solution you needed ..

Answer (score 0):

admin granted me the privilege to run `alter system flush shared_pool` from my database user, now everything is fine :)
                    – dziki